# Prisma Creating New Database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, graphql, prisma

I've got Prisma connected to my MongoDB but when I make any mutations, a new database is being created in MongoDB called `default_default` and data is being added there instead of the database I specified when going through the setup here

https://www.prisma.io/docs/get-started/01-setting-up-prisma-existing-database-JAVASCRIPT-a003/

I'd expect the data to be saved in the database specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.23
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mongo
            uri: 'mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/my-db-name'
```

Has anyone experienced something similar and found a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This you do in prisma.config by setting endpoint:

`endpoint: http://localhost:4466/graphql/default`

This will use database graphq_default